# City Construction Solution times out for large input

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, graph

**Problem**

> The country of Hackerland has `n` cities connected by `m`
>   uni-directional roads. The cities are numbered from `1` to `n`.
>   Recently the government decided to build new cities in Hackerland.
>
> Your task is to simulate `q` events. An event can have two types as
>   described below:
>
> - `1 x d` : A new city `n + 1` is constructed in the Hackerland and it is connected to city `x`. If `d = 0` the direction of the new road
>     is from `x` to `n + 1`. If `d = 1` the direction of the new road is
>     from `n + 1` to `x`.
> - `2 x y` : Print `Yes` if it's possible to move from city `x` to city `y`, print `No` otherwise.

**Constraints**

> 0 < n, m <= 50000
>
> 0 < q <= 10000
>
> x, y always correspond to an existing city in the Hackerland.
>
> Total number of cities in the Hackerland wont exceed 50000

You can find a full description of the problem [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/world-codesprint-11/challenges/hackerland)

**My Effort**

I tried to use a `BFS` here but all the test cases but the default are failing due to a timeout. For those test cases `n >= 4000. m >= 20000`.

**Code**

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque

n, m = map(int, input().split())

adjacentNodes = defaultdict(set)
for _ in range(m):
    u, v = map(int, input().split())
    adjacentNodes[u].add(v)

q = int(input())
for _ in range(q):
    c, x, d = map(int, input().split())

    if c == 1:
        n += 1
        y = n

        if d == 0:
            adjacentNodes[x].add(y)
        else:
            adjacentNodes[y].add(x)
    else:
        y = d
        visited = set()
        current = deque()
        current.append(x)
        answer = "No"
        while current:
            parent = current.popleft()
            if parent == y:
                answer = "Yes"
                break
            if parent in adjacentNodes:    
                for i in adjacentNodes[parent]:
                    if i not in visited:
                        visited.add(i)
                        current.append(i)
        print (answer)
```

**Question**

Does anyone have a suggestion how to optimise the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a tough one but I managed to solve it and pass all the test cases. Below are main points.

**Build a full directed graph first**

Save the queries because there can be up to `100,000` of them and it's more efficient to build a full graph first and then run all the queries on it.

**Find all strongly connected components**

Find all strongly connected components in the graph and then build a reachability map based on them. It has a lower space complexity since each strong component can be represented by a single node and so we don't need to have a reachability set for each node but only for its representative.

**Use DFS for finding reachability sets**

Modify a DFS so that after running it each connected component contains representatives (so-called low-link nodes) from other connected components that are reachable. But then, if a low link node is reachable so is any node from its connected component.

**Use memory efficiently for storing strong components**

Create an array of `(n + 1)` integer values, where `n` - the number of nodes in the graph. Index identifies a node in the graph and a value - all connected components (low link node) reachable from it. Value can have up to `n + 1` binary digits (if all nodes are reachable from the current one).

**Increase recursion limit**

As the number of nodes can reach `50000` so the recursion call stack must be set to this value.

**Solution Code**

```
from collections import defaultdict, deque
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(50001)

n, m = map(int, input().split())
adjacentNodes = defaultdict(set)
for _ in range(m):
    u, v = map(int, input().split())
    adjacentNodes[u].add(v)

q = int(input())
# read all queries first
queries = []
for i in range(q):
    c, x, d = map(int, input().split())
    if c == 1:
        n += 1
        y = n
        if d == 0:
            adjacentNodes[x].add(y)
        else:
            adjacentNodes[y].add(x)
    else:
        y = d
        queries.append((x, y))

# each node with number i corresponds to 2^i
nodeDpPosition = {i: (1 << i) for i in range(n + 1)}
# Implementation using the Tarjan algorithm
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm
def findAllConnectedComponents(edges):
    connectedComponents = [0 for _ in range(n + 1)]
    index = {'value' : 0}
    # map node to its connected component low link node
    connectedComponentLink = {}

    nodeStack = deque()
    indices = [-1] * (n + 1)
    lowLinks = [0] * (n + 1)
    onStack = [False] * (n + 1)

    def connectedComponent(node):
        indices[node] = index['value']
        lowLinks[node] = index['value']
        index['value'] += 1
        nodeStack.append(node)
        onStack[node] = True

        for adjacentNode in edges[node]:
            if indices[adjacentNode] < 0:
                connectedComponent(adjacentNode)
                lowLinks[node] = min(lowLinks[node], lowLinks[adjacentNode])
            elif onStack[adjacentNode]:
                # we have reached the previously visited node or come back in the call stack
                lowLinks[node] = min(lowLinks[node], indices[adjacentNode])

        if lowLinks[node] == indices[node]:
            while nodeStack:
                current = nodeStack.pop()
                connectedComponentLink[current] = node
                onStack[current] = False
                connectedComponents[node] |= nodeDpPosition[current]

                if current == node:
                    break

    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if indices[i] < 0:
            connectedComponent(i)

    return (connectedComponents, connectedComponentLink)

connectedComponents, connectedComponentLink = findAllConnectedComponents(adjacentNodes)

def advancedDfs(node):
    lowLinkNode = connectedComponentLink[node]

    neighbours = adjacentNodes.get(node)
    if neighbours is not None:
        for neighbour in neighbours:
            lowLinkNeighbourNode = connectedComponentLink[neighbour]
            if (connectedComponents[lowLinkNode] & nodeDpPosition[lowLinkNeighbourNode]) == 0:
                connectedComponents[lowLinkNode] |= nodeDpPosition[lowLinkNeighbourNode]
                advancedDfs(lowLinkNeighbourNode)

            connectedComponents[lowLinkNode] |= connectedComponents[lowLinkNeighbourNode]

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    advancedDfs(i)

for query in queries:
     x, y = query
     lowLinkXNode = connectedComponentLink[x]
     lowLinkYNode = connectedComponentLink[y]
     if connectedComponents[lowLinkXNode] & nodeDpPosition[lowLinkYNode]:
         print ("Yes")
     else:
         print ("No")
```